# Check Observable's value in Cypress component test

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to test my component which implements `ControlValueAccessor`. If I select an item from the dropdown then I want to make sure the formControl is updated with a specific value. This is what I have so far:

```js
cy
    .mount(
        '<form><app-boolean-select-with-tooltip [formControl]="formControl"/></form>',
        {
            imports,
            componentProperties: {
                formControl: new FormControl(null)
            }
        }
    )
    .then(wrapper => cy.wrap(wrapper).as('angular'))
    .get('igx-select')
    .click()
    .find('ugly selector here to pick the option')
    .click()
```

That part all seems to be working fine from looking at the test run.  The piece that I'm missing is, after that last `click` call, how do I check the value of the form control?